# Can this MySQL join query be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have this query which takes 27 seconds to execute:

```sql
SELECT ocal_files.*, count(DISTINCT ocal_favs.username) as favs 
FROM ocal_files
   INNER JOIN ocal_favs on ocal_favs.clipart_id = ocal_files.id 
GROUP BY ocal_files.id 
ORDER BY favs DESC​
```

(instead of username it should be user_id, because I have table for users)

`ocal_files` has 37457 rows and `ocal_favs` has 18263

**EDIT** result of explain

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT ocal_files.*, count(DISTINCT ocal_favs.username) as favs FROM ocal_files INNER JOIN ocal_favs on ocal_favs.clipart_i
d = ocal_files.id GROUP BY ocal_files.id ORDER BY favs DESC;                                                                             
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys  | key     | key_len | ref                             | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ocal_favs  | ALL    | rlb_clipart_id | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                             | 18622 | Using temporary; Using filesort|
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ocal_files | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | openclipart.ocal_favs.clipart_id |     1 | Using where                    |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Why is it slow? Can it be optimized? If yes then how?**

Comment: Are your tables indexed?

Comment: What is the execution plan? What are the indexes on the tables involved?

Comment: Have you [`ANALYZE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/analyze-table.html)d your tables yet? Can you ask MySQL to [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) the query?

Comment: @SimonRichter I've added result of EXPLAIN, Didn't know about ANALYZE it's speed up to 3.5 secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create an index on

```
ocal_favs ( clipart_id, username )
```

and make sure that there is a `NOT NULL` constraint on `ocal_favs.username` or add `ocal_favs.username IS NOT NULL` as a condition.

This should allow to get all information from `ocal_files` and that index.

Comment: I've never use indexes before do I need to call this query: `CREATE INDEX favs_index ON ocal_favs (clipart_id, username)`?

Comment: Because I trust people and I heard that indexes increase performance.

Comment: Indexes can certainly increase performance, and I assume that this one will help you, but don't trust anything that you can test instead :)

Answer (score 1):

A good approach when dealing with `SQL` optimization is to select ONLY fields you need, not all of them in your case. This almost always have a huge impact on performance, especially when fields are `BLOB's`.
And, as other users pointed out - the indexing is also very important, BUT only if you have created it properly.
A use of `LIMIT` clause is also good idea, if you do not have need to display your result at once (I`m in doubt that this is the case here, because I don't believe that you will display the result of 30000+ records to a user browser)...